# Can I pass GET string in UserAgent post method

Tags: perl

I call in this mode:

```
 my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
 my $response= $ua->post('www.example.com', {param1=>'val1',param2=>'val2'...} );
```

Can I call the above in the same way passing the values in GET form?:

```
 my $response= $ua->post('www.example.com?param=val1&param2=val2' );
```

It is because I'm using Firebug and when I go to Net tab under the "POST" tab it shows individual parameters as well as a GET string for POST submitted requests.
So I was wondering if I use GET string in this function call.

> Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Itemid    4 option    com_search
>   searchword    dsd task    search Source
>   Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 53
>   **searchword=dsd&task=search&option=com_search&Itemid=4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short you can pass GET strings yes, but if your end code does not accept GET METHOD it will fail.**

Also you might still need to specify some parameters since the post method asks for [`post(url,array_with_parameters)`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm).

```
sub post {
    require HTTP::Request::Common;
    my($self, @parameters) = @_;
    my @suff = $self->_process_colonic_headers(\@parameters, (ref($parameters[1]) ? 2 : 1));
    return $self->request( HTTP::Request::Common::POST( @parameters ), @suff );
}
```

Using along with `HTTP::Request` you can specify it at the content in the way you prefer:

```
# Create a user agent object
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");

# Create a request
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'http://www.example.com');
$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->content('searchword=dsd&task=search&option=com_search&Itemid=4');

# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
} else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

[**Read more...**](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP.pm#The_User_Agent)

Comment: Suppose I've entered "hi there" in comments text field. So firebug shows "hi+there" as the parameter. In $req->content should I then use this value with a "+" or as the original value?

Comment: @AgA I don't think so no, because it is being sent in POST, you can print it out at the page you receive it to make sure of it.

Comment: @AgA just to make sure of it I ran a test and it does not need to be encoded in any way if you are sending it with the above code. It will send as post just fine.